# Wordpress rewrite_rules not prepending index.php

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, iirf

I am unfortunately stuck on a Windows server running a WordPress site. My host has installed `iirf` for URL rewriting.

I finally got that working with a little finagling. However the `rewrite_rules` within WordPress is not prepending `index.php` when the matching rules are generated. Therefore, when the server sends a request like `index.php/foo/bar`, WordPress is trying to match it against `foo/bar`.

I have created a workaround that prepends `index` to the rules before they are recreated.

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_index');
function add_index($rules){

foreach ($rules as $rule => $rewrite) {
   if(!strpos($rules[$rule],'index.php') !== false) {
       unset($rules[$rule]);
       $rules['index.php/' . $rule] = $rewrite;
    }

}

return $rules;
```

}

This seems to be functioning correctly at the moment, but it seems that I am covering up an underlying problem. Shouldn't WordPress automatically be creating rules in this manner or is there a setting that I am missing that flags whether to add the `index.php`?